# Undetectable graphic card

Tags: windows-7, bios, gpu

Windows does not detect my graphic card. It worked under windoow 8 but since I formatted and installed windows 7 the card is undetectable. I have the STANDARD VGA ADAPTER card as if my card was the onboard chipset. To format from windows 8 to 7 I had to change some settings in my BIOS ( set some things to legacy in the boot options) so I could see my optic drives. Did this changed something ? because now if I used the default setitng in the BIOS I cant boot windows. I have to leave it to legacy. I guess this causes trouble finding the radeon card too? Anyway I did all the updates and installed the latest drivers for my Radeon HD 7670 and still its not detected by W7. I used GPU-Z and this is the output :

As you can see the specs are good (2 go, gddr5) but the name model and stuff is not detected. How can I make W7 detect this card?

[image]

[image]

Comment: GPU: Turnks -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Islands_%28GPU_family%29

Comment: Did you install the drivers from AMD/ATI yet?

Comment: @techie007 Yes I did with the cataclysm wizard. I choose the HD 7xxx serie with the right OS. Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to solve this:

1) Your GPU-z ID shows a the card to be from the [AMD Northern Islands (Turks) ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_Islands_%28GPU_family%29) family. That is a recent AMD card. Go to the AMD website and download their driver bundle (aka catalyst drivers) for all recent cards. Install. Reboot. Done.

An alternative way is to:

- Go to the device manager (which is now showing an unidentified VGA adapter).
- Right click in the adapter, choose properties
- Go to details and select 'Hardware IDs'. You should end up with something like this:[image]
- Google on the HW ID, you will find the name of the card.
- Go to website from ther manufacturer (AMD) and download the catalyst drivers. Install them. Reboot. Done.

Comment: Ok wow im really not a hardware person.Which is my AMD id in this ?  (Ill post a picture of this screen)

Comment: PCI ID 1002 is ATI (now bought by AMD). See http://www.pcidatabase.com/vendors.php     The values after the manufacturer ID are card model, HW revision etc.

Comment: ok im sorry i might sound stupid but I cant find how to get my drivers link with the info you gave me... this is just chinese to me...

Comment: I dont like asking questions when I don<t know what im talking about but this time im juste desperate ive been trying all day to update with the wizard or playin in the bios to make sure i didnt change anything bad

Comment: I posted my pictures in my question.

Comment: I have a Radeon HD 7670.. ??

Comment: I think this is the driver youw ant (though you will need to reboot after installing it)  http://www2.ati.com/drivers/hotfix/catalyst_12.6_hotfixes/catalyst_12-6_beta_windows7.exe

Comment: You sir !!! just saved my life thnks so much