# How to install VESA Graphics Drivers on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, graphics-card, resolution

I have a standard graphics card. When I use Windows 7 at 1024 x 768 resolution, my monitor screen shrinks from the left and right side by about 1.5 inches. Same is with bios and boot time. When I switch to 1280*1024 resolution  or something like that, I get a blank screen which reverts to 1024*768 resolution after 15 seconds.

While in ubuntu, working on the higher resolution is perfectly flawless and screen does not shrink. Also, at 1024*768 resolution, ubuntu also displays a shrinked screen. I guess that is due to the fact that I need VESA : MACH64GM drivers which are displayed in ubuntu. How do I install them in Windows 7? Windows update and self search could not find them and neither can I get them from Google.

Also, when I go to my monitor settings with the panel I have for monitor settings, I have an option that can restore the window size from standard to wide. But that makes the computer very laggy and videos don't play correctly. So I just want to keep to standard and get the ubuntu's high resolution view in Windows 7. Kindly tell me where to get those drivers, and how to get them working in Windows 7.

[image: Hardware ID of Standard VGA Adapter]

Comment: There are several posts on [SU] on how to find drivers using the PCI ID from the device. On the Ubuntu side you can display those with [`lspci`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci). On BSDs using [`pciconf`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pciconf&sektion=8) and on windows via [the device manager and then the properties of the card](http://superuser.com/questions/524953/undetectable-graphic-card).

Comment: Also, can you add if you are using an analog connection (either ancient VGA or analog DVI) or a digital connection? In the digital case the display should adjust itself.

Comment: @Hennes I'm using ANCIENT VGA connection.

Comment: Why am I now surprised at that? ;-) Anyway, I got no concrete answer. Just the question for the device ID to be added to the OP and the probably undesired workaround of running an OS with support (e.g. Ubuntu) and using a VM (with emulated more modern hardware) to run windows in. That will work, but with obvious caveeats. (sp?)

Comment: @Hennes I added the hardware IDS of the VGA Adapter. Also, running Windows 7 inside ubuntu will really be uncomfortable as I want to dedicate all of my 2 GB ram to Windows at a time.

Comment: PCI Vendor 1002 is ATI/AMD.  A quick google on `PCI\ven_1002 dev4752` yields [this page](http://www.downloadwindowsdrivers.info/pci/ven_1002/dev_4752/) as the first result. Following 80081002 lead to [this page for ATI Rage](http://www.downloadwindowsdrivers.info/pci/ven_1002/dev_4752/subsys_80081002/) with windows 2000 drivers. Sadly (NT/2000/XP) and (Vista/win7/win8) use different drivers, but you could try them anyway.  Make a backup first or have system restore turned on.

Comment: An alternative might be [http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/legacy-xp.aspx](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/legacy-xp.aspx) which at least has drivers for several ATI Rage cards and windows XP. Both are probably for 32 bit systems though, so sadly the best solution might be a cheap new card. New graphical cards can be found cheaply (e.g. a Radeon HD5450LP for less than €25) and might also be an option.

Comment: @Hennes that was what I was thinking that may I run XP Drivers under Windows7 with compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a pretty old chipset -- ATI Mach64GM. Sounds like the system is pre-2005.  I sugggest going to the ATI site and seeing if it can properly auto-detect and install the right drivers for Win7:
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx .  Reason for doing this is that I don't see a Win7 driver for the old card, but maybe the auto-detect will find one that works.

Otherwise, you're stuck with using a generic monitor driver, which probably is good enough anyway.

You can try making it so that you can see all display modes, even supposedly invalid ones:
Right-click on the desktop, choose "Screen Resolution".
Click Advanced Settings.
Click "List all Modes" and see if the resolution you want is there.
If not, click on the Monitor tab, and uncheck the box for "Hide all modes that this monitor cannot display."

The reason you are getting very limited resolutions offered is because the Mach64 is a very very limited, old, card and when it came out, 1024x768 was high-res!

Comment: Driver compatibility is not as simple as program compatibility (and if it's 64-bit Win7, you're SOL.) See if you can find a Vista driver, as those have a better chance of working. But for what 8MB can do, a generic driver should suffice.  That card was great in its day, but by 2007, it was already very obsolete & limited.  You could try forcing a different-but-similar ATI driver (worst case, revert to Safe Mode to remove it) but I'm not sure what you will gain beyond the generic driver.